# Duda sobre ordenacion de arrays en java

Tags: java

Hola tengo una duda para ordenar array's de menor a mayor sin utilizar métodos, en este código que tengo escrito, le pido al usuario 4 números y me dice si esta ordenada o desordenada, ahora bien utilizo un `for` para ordenarlo de mayor a menor pero me sale una excepción:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
> at ejercicio.Ejerciciosemanal.main(Ejerciciosemanal.java:33)

¿Alguien sabe alguna manera de arreglarlo o hacerlo mejor?, muchas gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] lista = new int[4];
        int i;
        int temp=0;
        boolean ordenado = true;
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print("Introduce el primer numero " + (i + 1)+":"+" ");
            lista[ i ] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 < lista.length) {
                if (lista[ i ] > lista[i + 1]) {
                    ordenado = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
       if (ordenado) {
            System.out.println("La lista está ordenada");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La lista está desordenada");
        }
        for(int j=0;j<lista.length;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<lista.length;k++) {
                if(lista[j-1]>lista[j]) {
                    temp=lista[j-1];
                    lista[j-1]=lista[j];
                    lista[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));
        
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo una versión funcionando, las explicaciones están en los comentarios pero básicamente, te salías de los límites porque tenías un índice negativo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] lista = new int[4];
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    boolean ordenado = true;
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("Introduce el primer numero " + (i + 1) + ":" + " ");
        lista[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < lista.length) {
            if (lista[i] > lista[i + 1]) {
                ordenado = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ordenado) {
        System.out.println("La lista está ordenada");
    } else {
        System.out.println("La lista está desordenada");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < lista.length; j++) {
        /* No hace falta empezar desde el principio otra vez, k = j hará que dé menos vueltas el loop
         ya que en teoría los valores anteriores ya han sido revisados*/
        for (int k = j; k < lista.length - 1; k++) {
            // Si j empieza en 0, j - 1 es -1... estás intentando acceder a un índice negativo
            if (lista[j] > lista[j + 1]) { /* Este j + 1 aquí es el motivo de que el bucle
            vaya hasta k < lista.length - 1, así no se sale*/
                temp = lista[j + 1]; // He modificado los accesos otra vez para evitar índices negativos
                lista[j + 1] = lista[j];
                lista[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));

}
```

Como puedes ver, teniendo un poco de cuidado con los índices da igual si empiezas el bucle en 0 hasta `length -1` o en 1 hasta `length`. El caso es tener en cuenta que dentro del bucle no puedes acceder a valores inferiores a 0 ni superiores a la longitud máxima, o te dará error!

Answer (score 0):

Hay un doble for anidado donde tienes esto:

```
if(lista[j-1]>lista[j])
```

Estas usando `j-1` como índice (de `lista`) cuando `j` vale 0. Eso hace que mires `lista[-1]`. Eso no va a funkar y vas a ver la excepción que indicas en la pregunta.

Comment: Esto va como respuesta o como comentario? :)

Comment: Podrías explicarle el como por qué dices eso?

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando muchos ciclos for te recomiendo usar el sort de Arrays de java.
Entiendo que lo que estás haciendo es pedir que se ingrese 4 números, verificar si está ordenado o no y si no está ordenado proceder a ordenarlo.

Dicho lo anterior te dejo el código un  poco optimizado (se puede optimizar aún más).

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] lista = new int[4];
            int i=0;
            boolean ordenado = true;
            String message="Introduce un numero en la posición:";
            
            while(i<4){//Se cambia por el for anterior
                System.out.print(message+" "+(i+1)); //Pedimos el ingreso de los 4 números  
                lista[ i ] = sc.nextInt();              
                i++;
            }
         

            for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
                if (i + 1 < lista.length) {
                    if (lista[ i ] > lista[i + 1]) {
                        ordenado = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
           if (ordenado) {
                System.out.println("La lista está ordenada");
            } else {
                System.out.println("La lista está desordenada, se procede a ordenar"+"\n");
                Arrays.sort(lista);//Esta linea estamos ocupanndo el ordenado de Arrays
            }
           
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));
            
        }
```

Saludos, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo tienes que cambiar el bucle que tienes al final de tu programa a esta forma:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lista.length; j++) {
    for (int k = j + 1; k < lista.length; k++) {
        if (lista[j] < lista[k]) {
                int aux = lista[j];
                lista[j] = lista[k];
                lista[k] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Al acceder a índices negativos del array, indica la excepción que nos muestras:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1